# Resize not resizing images with Capitial extension like JPG

Tags: plugin-development, images

I have used thie resize method to resize image and its working fine but only the problem which i am facing right now is that is not resizing image with extension in capital letter like JPG,JPEG,GIP. the same image will be resized if we just change the extension from JPG to jpg the image will be resized. Please let me know how can i fix this.

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor($targetFile); 
if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
 //$image->rotate( 90 );
  $image->resize( 300, 400, false );
  $image->save($targetFile); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because capital letter like JPG,JPEG,GIP are not the allowed mime types in wordpress.

For list of allowed mime types check the **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types)**.

Now to get your code work, you need to add the capital mime types into the allowed mime types.

You can do it by adding the following code in your active theme's **`functions.php`** file

```
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'wpse125310_mime_types' );
function wpse125310_mime_types( $output ) {
    $output['JPG'] = 'image/JPG';
    $output['JPEG'] = 'image/JPEG';
    $output['GIP'] = 'image/GIP';

    return $output;
}
```

You can add other mimetypes to the above too.